# Does wordpress give a disadvantage to your page speed score?

Tags: seo, performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I have a website for instance that only contains the default "Hello World" and other headers and internal links as it is a new wordpress installation. It uses the `Twenty Nineteen` theme which I believe should be optimized for speed. But my google page insights score is only at maximum around 76-78.

My friend who is a programmer, had a little pictures (about 3) and a plain purple background on the slider (no animation) on 1 page only as he showed me earlier, but with no animations on anything just yet, but was able to achieve a page insight score in google of around 99-100.

What explains the slow page speed on my side when I haven't even added any content to it yet?

Comment: Very little of your page speed score has to do with the content.  Most of it is from the server, the hosting, the content management system, and the theme.

Comment: Wordpress isn't the fastest CMS in the world. Cache it some more. If you don't need logged in users or dynamic content, it shouldn't matter what CMS you use.

Comment: I talked to my friend and so far the page is a static HTML page which explains why. He is manually coding the whole website for efficiency as well without using CMS